# C# Цикл For (при DataGridView)

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, closedxml

Появилась проблема, есть код (ниже написан):

```
var workbool = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook();
    var vari =  workbool.Worksheets.Add("Лист1"); 

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.RowCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    vari.Range("A" + i).Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                    vari.Range("B" + i).Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
                    vari.Range("C" + i).Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;
                    vari.Range("D" + i).Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value;
                    break;
                }
```

В чём тут косяк? как его остановить? в итоге код работает следующим способом: он всё сканирует и переписывает... Но не останавливается и до конца листа прописывает нули (пример ниже):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем `break` в цикле `for`? Да ещё без условия...

Comment: Что такое `vari`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Извиняюсь, в посте добавил (в коде)

Comment: @Streletz я ставил типо такого " if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == null)
                    {
                       
                        i--;
                       
                        
                    }" (но он не помог), а по поводу break сам не понимаю зачем.

Comment: @ElemStack, в таких случаях по условию делают заполнение ячеек. А, махинации с итератором цикла или `break` зачастую к добру не приводят. Тем более `break` там не нужен. Поэтому я и задал вопрос.

Comment: @Streletz тогда как мне построить for? чтоб он перетащил данный из datagridview2 в excel, который был создан и при этом чтоб остановился в нужный нам момент

Comment: Это зависит от конкретной задачи. Уточните вопрос. Поясните, пожалуйста, что Вы делаете и что Вы хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: @Streletz я перетаскиваю данные из datagridview2 в Excel. Задача стоит в том, чтобы 4 столбца были в Excel (начиная с 8-ой позиции (A8 B8 C8 D8). вот и всё.
Главное не используя "interop"! На данном примере использую ClosedXML

Comment: Попробуйте работать не с `datagridview`, а с источником к которому он привязан

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.RowCount; i++)
{
vari.Range("A" + (8+i)).Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
if (Convert.ToString(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) ==  null)
{
continue;
}
}
```

Было добавлено условие, при котором, если ячейка будет пустая, то остановить цикл и продолжить работу, при помощи "continue;"

> Благодаря использованию оператора continue в сочетании с выражением (
>   i < dataGridView2.RowCount) операторы между continue и концом текста
>   for пропускаются.